# What is the operator norm of this matrix $\left [\begin{smallmatrix}1&3\\2&0\end{smallmatrix}\right ]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&0\end{bmatrix}.$$**Question:** What is $\|A\|$?

Here, $\|A\|$ is the operator norm of $A$ in a sense that$$\|A\|=\inf \left \{C\geq 0:\|Ax\|\leq C\|x\|,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^2\right \}.$$Or, equivalently, in a senset that$$\|A\|=\sup \left \{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}:x\neq 0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^2\right\}.$$

**Trial 1)**$$AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}10&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}.$$And the characteristic equation becomes$$|AA^T-\lambda I|=(10-\lambda )(4-\lambda )-4=\lambda ^2-14\lambda +36,$$which has roots $\lambda _1=7+\sqrt{13}$ and $\lambda _2=7-\sqrt{13}$.
This leads to$$\|A\|=\sqrt{\|AA^T\|}=\sqrt{\max _i|\lambda _i|}=\sqrt{7+\sqrt{13}}.$$**Trial 2)** Although $A$ is not symmetric, it has full rank of eigenspace.
So I can proceeds as follows:$$|A-\lambda I|=(1-\lambda )(-\lambda )-6=\lambda ^2-\lambda -6=(\lambda -3)(\lambda +2).$$$\lambda _1'=-2$, $\lambda _2'=3$, $\max \limits _i\lambda _i'=3$.$$\|A\|=\max _i|\lambda _i'|=3.$$So, they don't coincide. Which answer is correct?

For a reference, I've read [Conrad : Computing the Norm of a Matrix](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/matrixnorm.pdf).

For a detailed explanation for the second trial, see my own answer below

Comment: You may indicate at the beginning the definition of the norm you are using.

Comment: Yeap. I've just added the definition of $||A||$.

Comment: So that is the $1$-norm, but then in trial 1 you compute the 2-norm. In trial 2 you compute somthing else. Why would that be the same?

Comment: If $A$ isn't symmetric it's just not true that the operator norm is the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue. The second computation is wrong.

Comment: @Gary Sorry, I can't catch up your explanation. So what is the right answer in the numerical value?

Comment: @Gary As for your comment, $||A||=\sqrt{||AA^T||}$ according to the reference I attatched, the reason for the equality is partially described in my own answer.  Where $||A||$ has the definition that I wrote above, and I can evaluate $||A||$ if $A$ is square, real and symmetric by evaluating the eigenvalues, right? And we can evaluate $||AA^T||$ instead.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah $A$ is not symmetric. But instead, $AA^T$ is symmetric. And we can evalute $||A||$ by the formula $||A||=\sqrt{||AA^T||}$. Is it wrong?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So is the first trial right?

Comment: @govin: yes, that's what you did in the first argument and that's fine. It's not what you did in the second argument and that argument is wrong.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, So.. the right answer is $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{13}}$ I think. And the second argument is false because $A$ is not symmetric (it is not orthogonally diagonalizable ; the eigenvectors are not perpendicular.) Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you thought  the second method should lead to a correct answer? (I of course am not going to find any problems with the first method.)

Comment: @KCd For the second method, I wrote down in detail in my own answer below. There, I've used two inequality to verify that $||A||=3$. But the first inequality (1) is wrong becase the eigenvectors of $A$ are not orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument would work if $A$ were unitarily diagonalizable. But it isn't, it is diagonalizable but not unitarily diagonalizable. Your $x_2$ as written is not an eigenvector for $A$. The eigenspace for $\lambda=3$ runs along $(3,2)$, which is not orthogonal to $(1,1)$.

To add, even before calculating anything: a real matrix with real eigenvalues is unitarily diagonalizable if and only if it is symmetric.

Comment: I think I understand your first sentence. $A$ is diagonalizable, for eigenvectors for $A$ are, for example (3,2) and (1,-1) and they are not orthogonal right? So $A$ is not orthogonally diagonalizable(or equivalently, not unitarily diagonalizable). right?

Comment: Yes indeed. $\ $

Comment: But. Please give me the answer to the original question. I know you're smart. But I'm fool. So please let me know the answer? Is it 3? or $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{13}}$?

Comment: You expect the wrong argument to give the right answer? Your first argument was fine, as you were already told.

Comment: You can say more simply. Sorry for my foolness. I can't understand your first sentence. Anyway. I think the right answer is $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{13}}$. The second trial and my own answer is wrong owing to the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not perpendicular (And I think this is what you are talking about orthogonal(unitary) diagonalizabilty). In short, the first argument is valid only when $A$ is symmetric, provided that $A$ is real matrix. Thanks!

Comment: No. Your first argument is valid always. Your second argument works only when $A$ is selfadjoint ( which in the real case is the same as symmetric).

Comment: My mistake. Second argument is valid only when $A$ is symmetric, provided that $A$ is real matrix. And, ok self-adjoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**A detailed explanation for the second trial**.

The matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$$
has characteristic polynomial $(1-\lambda)(-\lambda)-6=(\lambda+2)(\lambda-3)$.
Let $\lambda_1=-2$ and $\lambda_2=3$.
Then
\begin{align*}
A+2I&=\begin{bmatrix}3&3\\2&2\end{bmatrix}\\
A-3I&=\begin{bmatrix}-2&3\\2&-3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and the corresponding unit eigenvectors are
$$x_1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }
x_2=\begin{bmatrix}\frac3{\sqrt{13}}\\\frac{-2}{\sqrt{13}}\end{bmatrix}.$$
They form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^2$.
Now, for any $x\in\mathbb R^2$,
$$x=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$$
for some $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb R$.
It follows that
\begin{align*}
Ax
&=A(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)\\
&=c_1(Ax_1)+c_2(Ax_2)\\
&=\lambda_1c_1x_1+\lambda_2c_2x_2
\end{align*}
and that
$$\frac{||Ax||^2}{||x||^2}=\frac{{\lambda_1}^2{c_1}^2+{\lambda_2}^2{c_2}^2}{{c_1}^2+{c_2}^2}\le\left(\max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\}\right)^2.$$
Then
$$\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}\le\max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\},$$
and we can take the supremum on the left hand side, for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$, to conclude
$$||A||\le3.\tag{1}$$

For the converse inequality, we have
$$|\lambda_1|=\frac{||Ax_1||}{||x_1||}\le||A||.$$
This is similarly true for $i=2$, and thus,
$$3=\max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\}\le||A||.\tag{2}$$

By (1) and (2), we have $||A||=3$

My point is that, although $A$ is not symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalizable and we can get $||A||$ just by evaluating the eigenvalues of $A$, not by evaluating the eigenvalues of $AA^T$.
But, is the second trial right?

Comment: This argument is wrong, since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not orthogonal.