# Compute the matrix norm of $A$= $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 2\\ -1& 2\\\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Compute the matrix norm of $A$= $\begin{pmatrix}2 &2\\ -1& 2\\\end{pmatrix}$

**My attempt**

I found $A^T$ = $\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1\\ 2& 2\\\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^TA$= $\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2\\ 2& 8\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Then det($A^TA$ - $\lambda$$I_2$) of $A^TA$.

From this I got $\lambda^2$-  13$\lambda$ +36.

I put this into the quadratic formula and got the roots $\frac{13+\sqrt25}{2}$. Is this my answer? Or is my answer $\sqrt9$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501765/what-is-the-operator-norm-of-this-matrix-left-beginsmallmatrix13-20-end), asked a couple of minutes ago? If so, it would be good to mention it for context.

Comment: No it is not. @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the square root, not of the trace of the product, but of its *spectral radius* which is the largest absolute value of any eigenvalue. Here, we see that the eigenvalues solve the quadratic equation

$\lambda^2-13\lambda+36=0.$

If we try different rational roots that divide $36$ and must be positive by [Descartes'Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), we find roots of $4$ and $9$ (thus $(\lambda-4)(\lambda-9)=0$). So the largest absolute value of any eigenvalue of the product is $9$, and the square root is $3$ which is the (Euclidean) norm of the original matrix.

Comment: yes this is what I got. Thank you!